# display library 'carbon' not available

Tags: osdev, bochs

i'm currently making an os, and have an issue, and wanna debug what's going on. I'm on mac, i use bochs.
So basically i ran bochs -f bochs_config, and bochs_config:

```
megs: 128
romimage: file=/usr/local/Cellar/bochs/2.7/share/bochs/BIOS-bochs-latest, address=0xfffe0000
vgaromimage: file=/usr/local/Cellar/bochs/2.7/share/bochs/VGABIOS-lgpl-latest
floppya: 1_44=build/main.img, status=inserted
boot: floppy
mouse: enabled=0
display_library: carbon
```

and for some reason it gave me this error: "bochs_config:7: display library 'carbon' not available" like what? When i go to install it with homebrew i dont see the package 'carbon' anywhere so... i'm stuck.

Comment: I'm curious what happens if you use `sdl2` instead of `carbon`

Comment: then it does run, but gives this error: "00000000000p[SDL2  ] >>PANIC<< Unknown sdl2 option 'gui_debug'" (its not happy with the gui_debug option, and if i remove it, it gives me the command line debugger, and i want the gui debugger.) + it also gives this error if i try to `continue`: "00022013731p[BIOS  ] >>PANIC<< No bootable device.
"

Comment: Possibly your BOCHS was not built with GUI debugger support. You may have to build it from source and provide all the build options including the GUI debugger support.

Comment: @MichaelPetch ok, i'll try compiling it to see if that works.